# Reflection like features with C

Tags: c#, c, dynamic, reflection

I am wondering how I can call functions in C dynamically without typing the function call in the code.
I have different Messages, for example: `START`, `STOP`, `TEST`.
I have functions in a library: `process_msg_START`, `process_msg_STOP`, `process_msg_TEST`.
I want to call the correct function without typing the Name explicitly, something like using Reflections or the dynamic runtime in C#.
Do you have any Ideas? I am very new to C and my search wasn’t successful.

Comment: The closest you are going to get is to have a predefined table that matches a string to a function to call. Otherwise standard C doesn't have any kind of reflection or introspection capabilities at all.

Comment: int (*fp1)(double) = func1; I think you want something like this - storing the pointer to a function in variable then call it (or in your case creating the structure with fields corresponding to functions).

Comment: It's the metadata .NET produces that allows reflection. If there is a C solutions to your problem, it will be by a very different mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the compiled program doesn't know the functions' names after the compiler/linker have done their job. Interpreted languages like C# retain most of the source code while the program is running, therefore the interpreter can search the code base for certain functions (I don't claim to know how reflection actually works though).

Your only solutions there is to either have a map that binds a string/enum to a function pointer, or do a similar process with a scripting language in your code base (like Lua)

Answer (score 1):

- structure with members "name" (string) and "fn" (function pointer);
- array of such structures;
- loop which scan for correct name and call corresponding function by the pointer;

Comment: I was looking for more dynamic solution, but the question was already answered and it is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are new to c++ then learning the precompiler directives may take you some of the way. E.g. this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
//#define TEST "true"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "a";
    #ifdef TEST
    std::cout << "b";
    #endif
    std::cout << "c";

    return 0;
}
```

Remove the // in the row with #define to print "b"